# NA when trying to summarize a subset of data (R)

Tags: r, dataframe, na, missing-data

Whole vector is ok and has no `NAs`:

```
> summary(data$marks)
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
   1.00    6.00    6.00    6.02    7.00    7.00

> length(data$marks)
[1] 2528
```

However, when trying to calculate a subset using a criteria I receive lots of `NAs`:

```
> summary(data[data$student=="John",]$marks)
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max.    NA's 
  1.000   6.000   6.000   6.169   7.000   7.000     464

> length(data[data$student=="John",]$marks)
[1] 523
```

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example.  Additionally, instead of `data[data$student=="John",]$marks` I would recommend, `data[data$student=="John", "marks"]`, it is more traditional as well as easier to read

Comment: Are there missing values for `student`. If any values of `student` are missing, even if there are no missing values for `student=="John"` and no missing values for `marks`, then you would get `NA`s. What happens if you do `summary(data[which(data$student=="John"), ]$marks)`?

Comment: Yes, there are actually missing values for `student`. However, what is the logic behind it if I specified certain using exact match? What is a solution then?

Comment: NA gets pulled out by `==` - `x <- c(1,2,NA); x[x==1]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is that you have missing values for `student`. As a result, when you subset by `student`, all the `NA` values for student end up producing `NA` for `marks` when you take your subset. Wrap the subsetting condition in `which()` to avoid this problem. Here are a few examples that will hopefully clarify what's happening:

```
# Fake data
set.seed(103)
dat = data.frame(group=rep(LETTERS[1:3], each=3), 
                 value=rnorm(9))
dat$group[1] = NA

dat$value
dat[dat$group=="B", "value"]
dat[which(dat$group=="B"), "value"]

# Simpler example
x = c(10,20,30,40, NA)

x>20
x[x>20]

which(x>20)
x[which(x>20)]
```

Comment: Can you add a solution then please?
So I need to leave `NAs` in my dataset (so subsetting won't work in my case), but to calculate summary without them.

Comment: Wrap your subset in `which()` as in my example. `which` returns the indices of the rows that match the condition, ignoring NA values.

Answer (score 0):

First Note that `NA=="foo"` results in NA. When subsetting a vector with a NA value the result is NA.

```
t = c(1,2,3)
t[c(1,NA)]
```

Answer (score 0):

a `tidyverse` solution.  I find these to be easier to read than base R.

```
library(tidyverse)

data %<%
  filter(student == "John") %<%
  summary(marks)
```